# Fetching strings before special characters from a postgres column

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a column with following values in a postgres table.

```
col1
uniprotkb:P62158(protein(MI:0326), 9606 - Homo sapiens)
uniprotkb:O00602-PRO_0000009136(protein(MI:0326), 9606 - Homo sapiens)
```

I would like to extract a value from above column values.

```
col2
P62158
O00602
```

I am using following regexp match on my column

```
select 

        uniprotkb:(.*)\-|\([a-zA-Z].* as col2

from table;
```

But the above regexp capture the text before the last '-'. I want to capture the text between uniprotkb: and before the first occurence of either '(' or '-'. Any suggestion here would be helpful.

Comment: Well, it seems the requirement you mention does not quite match your pattern. Did you mean to use `uniprotkb:(.*?)[-(][a-zA-Z].*`? The greedy `*` is only a part of the problem, isn't it?

Comment: Are you using `regexp_matches`?

Comment: Yes, I am using regexp_matches

Comment: So, you may even use `uniprotkb:(.*?)[-(][a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
uniprotkb:(.*?)[-(][a-zA-Z]
           ^^^ ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tuptAa/2).

**Details**

- `uniprotkb:` - a literal string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `[-(]` - a `-` or `(`
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter.

PostgresSQL test:

```
SELECT (REGEXP_MATCHES (
      'uniprotkb:P62158(protein(MI:0326), 9606 - Homo sapiens)',
      'uniprotkb:(.*?)[-(][a-zA-Z]'
   ))[1]
```

Outputs:

[image]